# Distributed cgroup?

Tags: linux, distributed

I have process1 in Node A and process 2 in NodeB. Is there any way I can enforce a memory and cpu limit for the two processes together? That is the net resource requirement for the two processes should be capped rather than enforcing an individual cap. (If I had process1 and 2 in the same node, I could have specified a cgroup subsytem with the net cpu and memory share and added the two processes.)

Comment: Super late to this, but when you say Node A and Node B, did you mean two independent systems or one system with one OS, but two processes running on separate NUMA nodes?